# Изменение скорости движения Motion Layout

Tags: java, android

Скорость движения задается через .xml.

Как можно изменить `duration` через код?

```
        <Transition
        motion:autoTransition="animateToEnd"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/start"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/end"
        motion:duration="5000" />
```

Comment: Что если посмотреть документацию, очень много ответов можно найти в самых очевидных местах. https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/motion/widget/MotionLayout#setTransitionDuration(int) . Преимущество такого подхода в том, что вы получаете решение менее, чем за минуту, а не ждете часами, когда кто то сделает это за вас. Я вот вообще думаю, что не стоит лезть в разработку не читая документации, но кто меня спрашивает ..

Comment: Это я видел, спасибо. Если задаю  motion_container.setTransitionDuration(1000); - то меняется скорость только в одну сторону, а я пытаюсь понять, как сделать изменение скорости в обе стороны

Comment: Если вы хотите получить полезный ответ, то проблему надо излагать в вопросе максимально подробно и конкретно, а не как вы спрашиваете "каким методом менять duration", а в комментарии потом пишите, что вы использовали этот метод, но он не  меняет скорость и в другую сторону. Это несколько разные проблемы, вам самому так не показалось? Что вы желали увидеть в ответе, что кто то волшебным образом сам догадается, что у вас в другую сторону не работает? Под вопросом есть кнопка "править", воспользуйтесь ей и изложите свою проблему так, чтобы другим тоже было понятно, в чем именно она заключается